# Field with multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is there a way to get a field with multipile lines without using the  tags?

http://croakedslayouts.hol.es/purchase.html

I would like the size of the field to be the size the image is atm, and I dont like the  tag because the user can change the size of it with the thing in the bottom right corner.

I'd also like to be able to customize it with a script like I have the name and email fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way you can have multiple lines on an `<input type='text'>`.  In order to do that you would need a textarea element.

To prevent users from resizing the textarea, add `resize: none;` to the CSS of the element.